# find & kill the processes on mount point folder before umont

Tags: linux, rhel, mount, kill, lsof

I just wonder if somewhere we have some command that gives the following

- we have server - RHEL 7.2 redhat version

usually before `umount` on *mount point folder* , we need to kill the PIDS that related mount point folder

example

lets say we want to perform

```
umount  /golden/mnt1
```

So we need to kill all PID that related to `/golden/mnt1`

example

```
lsof /golden/mnt1
```

gives the PIDS as

```
54642
5459
65753
6581
94763
4826
```

so we need to kill all above PIDS

only then we can do safety `umount  /golden/mnt1`

what we are searching , is maybe command that do both approach of `lsof` and `kill all PIDS`

appreciate to get ideas about this

Comment: Previous discussions with you *did* mention `xargs`, didn't they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fuser -k -m /golden/mnt1
```

See [man fuser](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser)